# Использование анимации в datatrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Здравствуйте!

На днях возник вопрос, а можно ли использовать анимацию с триггером DataTrigger. Погуглил и некоторые люди утверждают что это вполне возможно. Стал пробовать и, к сожалению, у меня не получилось. Вот мой простой, нерабочий пример анимации с datatrigger:

```
    <Page.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Executing}" 
                             Value="false">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                    From="500 0 -500 0" 
                                                    To="0" 
                                                    DecelerationRatio="0.9" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                 From="0"
                                                 To="1"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Page.Style>
```

Если кто-то сталкивался, прошу помочь разобраться. Спасибо!

Comment: Page.Margin? А установка этого свойства _без_ анимации работает?

Comment: анимация отлично работает с EventTrigger.

Comment: Page.Margin выдаёт ошибку "Не удается разрешить все ссылки на свойства в пути свойств Page.Margin"

Comment: Нет, я не об этом. Я о том, что если вы объекту типа `Page` установите свойство `Margin`, будет ли от этого какой-то эффект?

Comment: Эффекта нет, пробовал(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно.

Ваш код наглядный тому пример - работает правильно.

В подтверждение привожу гифку, разница только в большей длительности анимации и цвета фона для `Page`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка где-то еще - создавайте воспроизводящий пример.

Comment: То есть вы просто скопировали мой код и он заработал?

Comment: добавил два триггера на false и true, кнопкой изменяю состояние, но почему-то срабатывает только один триггер со значением true.

Comment: немного неверно, срабатывает только последний триггер, но условие учитывается

Comment: @Евгений Смелов "То есть вы просто скопировали мой код и он заработал? " Да, просто скопировал ваш код. Об этом прямо написано в ответе.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов "немного неверно, срабатывает только последний триггер, но условие учитывается " то есть вопрос исчерпан?

Comment: Я всё равно не могу понять, почему триггер срабатывает выборочно. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов что значит выборочно? Вы что хотите запускать эту анимацию несколько раз?

Comment: Да, хочу запускать, как только изменится значение

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов ну это совсем другое дело. Вы какой вопрос задавали? Можно ли использовать анимацию с DataTrigger. Ответ был дан. Если у вас проблема с какой-то другой конкретной анимацией, то задавайте другой вопрос. Так, совет на будущее. Теперь по теме - вам нужно еще и обращать анимацию при изменении состояния на `true`, так как значения свойств зафиксировались и стартовая точка уже не актуальна.

Comment: И как быть в данном случае?

Comment: @ЕвгенийСмелов так ведь написал уже - "нужно еще и обращать анимацию при изменении состояния на true"